# How can I get the order date, in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I can see inside `class-wc-admin-cpt-shop_order.php` there are some functions that are pulling together the order information for display in WooCommerce. However, I don't see anywhere where the date can be used ...

Because WooCommerce uses `wp_posts` to store the data, can I assume that the `post_date field` is the correct one to use?

Also, anyone know whether there is a function in WooCommerce to get this, or whether there is a way of getting the date to come out in `class-wc-admin-cpt-shop_order.php`.

Comment: Hi d74p, your suggested change to start the sentence with "because" instead of "since" is grammatically incorrect.

Answer (score 30):

```
// Get $order object from order ID 
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Get Order Dates
$order->get_date_created();
$order->get_date_modified();
$order->get_date_completed();
$order->get_date_paid();
```

Source: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-order-info-total-items-etc-from-order-object/

---

**Additionally**

```
$order->get_date_created();
```

Is the "order date", which you can change within WooCommerce ("Edit Order")

[image]

Comment: Make it display pretty with `wc_format_datetime()`

Answer (score 21):

You can use the [WC_Order](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/7b2aec4791c19fe63ceea450c79924d6b38f9013/includes/class-wc-order.php) object, if you have the order ID:

```
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
$order_date = $order->order_date;
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `wc_get_order( $order_id );`

Comment: @helgatheviking , what's the advantage of using `wc_get_order()` in this case? As far as I know, `wc_get_order()` would just end up calling `get_post()`, since the supplied argument is numeric. It's possible I'm missing something.

Comment: `new WC_Order($order_id)` is also going to call [`get_post()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/53a1538d1b46cc5234c407880175e06f13b33a0e/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L117) if the argument is numeric. It's a little I say tomato you say tomahto.... ie, almost no difference. If you forced me I'd say the `wc_get_order()` will probably not change and if they changed something about the `WC_Order()` class the wrapper would still work.

Comment: Is there an "order_completed_date" field?

Comment: To answer my own question above, `<?php echo $order->get_date_completed(); ?>` is what I needed.

Comment: Use woocommerce 3 and above, Order properties should not be accessed directly.

Comment: It cannot be accessed directly.

Answer (score 9):

Order properties should not be accessed directly. Best way is `$order->get_date_completed()`